# How to add dynamic controls using model class in mvc without loop or jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**How to convert model class into dynamic controls in the view without a loop?** I  want to create if checkbox than show checkbox control if dropdown than show dropdown if text than create textbox.

```
 public class DataSources
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("text")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("text")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("checkbox")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("dropdown")]
        //[Column(TypeName = "dropdown")]
        public List<DataSources> MyList { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean in the second sentence. Do you mean if a checkbox is selected, then an additional checkbox and dropdown menu will appear?

Comment: [DisplayName("checkbox")] i write that for understanding, that this model class generate textboxes,checkbox if datatype is bool and dropdown if datatype is list

Comment: Provide more details. The question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Editorfor` HTML helper which binds the control based on the model type. For an example, if the type is a string then it will take textbox and if it is a list, it will bind the dropdown:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Propertyname)
```

You can find the link here for details explanation - https://www.steelcm.com/how-to-use-the-html-editor-for-method/

Comment: You can add a class like : @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.MyProperty,
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "MyCssClass" } }). I do not understand when you say complete class.

Comment: i say about that model class, without add property name. only one line use for create controls without loop

Comment: Class has only attributes which are used to set display names, validations. I don't remember any property which uses for generating the controls dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

i understand that what do you want, you want to show controls only use of one line than you can use this

```
@model MVCApp.Models.DataSource
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

by use of this its automatically create dynamic controls.

Comment: thanks man i want to use something like this,  i use this its working.

Answer (score 0):

The class does not support any such property to manage these things dynamically. One way around to implement this is as follows :

My ActionResult Method be like(Consider this as sample data) :

```
DataSource model = new DataSource();
model.MyList = new List<DataSource>();
var data = new DataSource()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "test"
 };
 model.MyList.Add(data);
 return View(model);
```

This will return data to the View. And your View should be like as below :

```
@model MVCApp.Models.DataSource

@if (Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name).ToString() == "text")
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
}
@if (Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Phone).ToString() == "text")
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)
}

@if (Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Active).ToString() == "checkbox")
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active)
}
@if (Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.MyList).ToString() == "dropdown")
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id,
                new SelectList(Model.MyList.Select(x=>x.Name)),
                "-- Select --")
}
```

This worked for me. 
You need to create your own HTML helper to achieve this more effectively.

Let me know if this helps!